# Mean of variable of alters in R

Tags: r, loops, data-cleaning, network-analysis

I have a network data set of a school, where I have the level of depression for each respondent. The data looks like this:

```
id  depression friendid_1 friendid_2 friendid_2 friendid_3
1      1.0        7          3          6          5
2      0.6        6          4          NA         NA
3      0.0        1          4          5          7
4      1.8        9          3          8          2
```

I want to add a variable to the data that is the mean depression of the respondent's network (so averaging the depression level of all the alters who also exist in this data as respondents).

Any help would be great!

Comment: `dataset$mean_depression = mean(dataset$depression)`

Comment: @Jorge this would give me the mean for the whole dataset right? I was looking to get the means for each ego network

Comment: Would you `dput()` the table you provided so others can reproduce it?

Answer (score 3):

With these type of "connected" problems I like to use the `igraph` package to treat the data like a graph/network. So with your sample data

```
dd<-read.table(text="id  depression friendid_1 friendid_2 friendid_3 friendid_4
1      1.0        7          3          6          5
2      0.6        6          4          NA         NA
3      0.0        1          4          5          7
4      1.8        9          3          8          2", header=TRUE)
```

We can create a graph of your data with

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr) #for select
library(tidyr) #for gathter
gg <- dd %>% select(-depression) %>% 
  gather(friend, friend_id, -id) %>% 
  select(-friend) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(, directed=FALSE) %>% #this assumes friendships are mutual
  simplify()
gg <- set_vertex_attr(gg, "depression", V(gg)[dd$id], dd$depression)
plot(gg)
```

[image]

Then you can loop over all the vertices and calculate the mean depression of the neighbors

```
sapply(V(gg), function(v) {
  mean(neighbors(gg, v)$depression, na.rm=TRUE)
})
#   1   2   3   4   7   6   9   5   8 
# 0.0 1.8 1.4 0.3 0.5 0.8 1.8 0.5 1.8
```

Comment: I'm getting this error for the code right before the plot command: Error in simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) : Unknown vertex selected

Comment: Maybe try `gg <- set_vertex_attr(gg, "depression", V(gg)[as.character(dd$id)], dd$depression)`? It works with the sample data for me so a reproducible example would be helpful.